# Wrong number using label in subfloat with subfig and caption=false

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats, ieeetran

I'm using the IEEEtran class, and I need to use the `subfig` package with the `caption=false` option. However, when I use the package like this

```
\documentclass{article}
% Remove the caption=false and this work as intended
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{My tables}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[\label{tab:1}]{%
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a & b\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
foo & bar\\\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}%
}&%
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a & b\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
foo & bar\\\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:2}
}%subfloat
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Testing a reference to \ref{tab:1} and \ref{tab:2}.        
\end{document}
```

I obtain the reference to `2a` and `2b` instead of `1a` and `1b`. However, if I remove the `caption=false` everything works fine. But, I'm require to use that part, so the IEEEtran class can put the correct formatting to the captions.

What solution do I have? I tried to move the `\label` around, as you can see in both cases, but both have the same result.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: The problem is that if I add `caption` (that is the same as removing the `caption=false`--I think) removes the special format that the IEEEtran uses. Note that I didn't put `IEEEtran` in the document class, but if you use it you will see the difference.

Comment: Well, it keeps the roman number style. However, `IEEEtran` normally uses text all caps, but when using `caption` explicitly the words are normal (not capitalized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dirty trick is to load the [caption package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) *before* the document class. That way the [subfig package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) is happy, and the document class settings that format captions overwrite those of the caption package.

```
\RequirePackage{caption}
\let\abovecaptionskip\relax
\let\belowcaptionskip\relax
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My tables}
\label{table1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a & b\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
foo & bar\\\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:1}
}&%
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a & b\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
foo & bar\\\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:2}
}%subfloat
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Testing a reference to \ref{tab:1} and \ref{tab:2}.        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dirty or not, that did the work. Is not advised to do this kind of loading before? or there is any drawback of doing it?

Comment: In general, loading a package before the document class is not supported, and there can be side effects, but I don't think there are any in this case.